# Placement of backbutton in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm using a navigation controller, and I want to replace the default back button and text, with a custom. Here is what I do:

```
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "BackCarretIcon")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "BackCarretIcon")
```

This is set in prepare for segue, before navigating away from the root view controller.

When the next view controller appears, the image appears to be in the right place, but when the push animation has completed, the back button image moves a bit down. See image of the destination view controller:

[image: describing image]

**So the "BackCarretIcon" and "back" label are not vertical center alligned. How come?? and how can this be fixed.**

There is no code in the view controller life cycle methods of the destination view controller, that uses the navigationcontroller or navigation items.

**EDIT**

I've put a breakpoint in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in the destination view controller. It breaks two times, before the destination view controller appears on screen. When i continue execution after the second break, the destination view controller is pushed onto the screen(with the back carret in the right place). When it is fully pushed onto the screen, the back carret jumps a couple of points down, to the wrong position, and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` breaks again.

I'm not able to break, at the place where the back carret is positioned right...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -2), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference... I tried with higher values on `vertical` too. And tried placing it both in prepare for segue, and in the destination view controllers viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Back button is property of the second last VC in the stack of VCs of navigation view controller.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BackBack" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Put this in a child VC in a navigation VC & push another VC on top to it. Back button will display "BackBack". So proper way to do this would be to do this for every child VC. Here user will know that last VC was about "BackBack". But try not to do this. Inform user about where back button will take them. Hacking the way back button works might not be best way & might cause some problem.

Hope this helps.